# Marginal products of labor and capital (cobb-douglas)

Tags: economics

Given the cobb-douglas function $Y=1.01*K^{0.25}L^{0.75}$

$Y=$output; $K=$capital; $L=$labor

How can I determine the marginal products of labor and capital? Not used in this equation. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Go back to your definitions: Marginal product of labour = $\frac{\partial Y}{\partial L}$, and similarly for capital.

Comment: So I'll be getting an equation as my answer?

Comment: @DC22287 You´ll get an expression for $\frac{\partial Y}{\partial L}$. This can be written as an equation $\frac{\partial Y}{\partial L}=\ldots$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The marginal product is defined as the partial derivative with respect to the respective input.

In your case $\frac{\partial Y}{\partial L}=1.01 * 0.75 * ( \frac{K}{L})^{0.25}$ for labor and $\frac{\partial Y}{\partial K}=1.01 * 0.25 * ( \frac{K}{L})^{0.75}$ for capital.